# Understanding "non-WAAS G1000" in a 2006 Turbo 182

Tags: g1000

All,
I am trying to get my head around something my local avionics shop is telling me about a 2006 T182 that has a GTX345R fitted. Surely, the GTX345R adds WAAS capability but he referred to this configuration as a "non-WAAS G1000"

I feel like you'd need to be Stephen Hawking to understand this stuff!

Can anyone shed light on the way in which the addition of a GTX345R (replacing GTX-33) means it is not WAAS???

Thanks in advance,
Michael.

Answer (score 4):

The GTR345R is a transponder that can be purchased with a built-in WAAS GPS ([link](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/140954))—which this one apparently has. So it provides the WAAS GPS positioning required for ADSB. The GPS in the transponder does not provide a GPS source to the G1000.

From what the shop said, it looks like the G1000 is an older version that is not WAAS capable. That’s probably why they chose to install the transponder with built-in WAAS since it was much cheaper than upgrading the G1000.

Comment: "The GPS in the transponder does not provide a GPS source to the G1000."

That was the info I was missing - thank you for the quick and easily comprehensible response!